# CKEditor- acf content filter/ allowed content not working as expected

Tags: javascript, validation, ckeditor

This is a two questions in one:

Q1) I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/anik786/L8kb4nes/1/

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" cols="80" rows="10">
        Example Text
    </textarea>
    <button id="btnOutput">Get Data</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

and the JS:

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        allowedContent:
        'h1 h2 h3 p blockquote strong em;' +
        'a[!href];' +
        'img(left,centre, right)[!src,alt,width,height];' +
        'figure figcaption;' +
        'table tr th td caption;' +
        'span{!font-family};' +
        'span{!color};' +
        'span(!marker);' +
        'span(!math-tex);' +
        'del ins'
    });

$("#btnOutput").on("click", function(){
    $('#output').text(editor.getData());
});
```

If I go to the source mode and enter something invalid like: <h4>Hi</h4> and go back to the WYSIWIG and then click the "get data" button then the h4 tag turns to a p tag in the output. This is also verfied when going back to the source mode. This is as expected as h4 is not in the allowed content.

However, if I go to the source mode and write <h4>Hi</h4> and then straight away click the "get data" button (i.e. without switching back to the WYSIWIG), the h4 tag appears on the output.

How can I fix this?

Q2) The content filter does not seem to work with script tags. like

```
<script src="bad.js></script>
```

When switching back and forth the wyswig, this tag does not dissapear. Why?

Comment: I JUST found a 'okay' way of achieving this.

I changed the output button code to this:

    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setMode( 'wysiwyg', function() {
                $('#output').text(editor.getData());
            } ); 

this essentially forces the editor to change to wyswig mode and THEN get the data. However I want to avoid this please as this could irritate users if their editor just keeps changing modes automatically!

Comment: Q1: Don't allow your users to do that. ACF is not really an airthight security feature. For real security, you have to sanitize the input serverside. If you have security concerns remember: Never trust anything from the browser. Q2: Wth? It should. It does for me! Can you show us any online instance of CKE where this happens? Massive bug if it happens!

Comment: Try the jsfiddle link above. I recall it did not work there.

Comment: Regarding Q2: That's not a valid script tag though. Will a browser run that? See http://jsfiddle.net/L8kb4nes/5/

Comment: Well there is a simple reason for that. I'm an idiot. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I JUST found a 'okay' way of achieving this.

I changed the output button code to this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setMode( 'wysiwyg', function() {
            $('#output').text(editor.getData());
        } );
```

this essentially forces the editor to change to wyswig mode and THEN get the data. However I want to avoid this please as this could irritate users if their editor just keeps changing modes automatically!